# load any component based on valid token in Angular5

Tags: angular5

I have token in localStorage, I want to redirect every attempt to load any component with invalid token. How can I do it? 
It is possible to do with `onInit()` function but how could I implement it to every component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (valid token) {
          return true
        } else { // invalid token, force to redirect
          this.router.navigate(['/redirectUrl']); 
          return false;
        }
      }
}
```

and the routing:

```
....
    { path: 'myRoute', component: MyComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
...
```